# How can I draw underneath the navigation bar / gesture bar in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm looking to replicate what the Android Messages app does - the gesture bar 'floats' over the bottom of the page and content scrolls behind it. I'm not sure what else to say -- I've tried a number of different attributes in the Scaffold widget but none do the trick. I can't find an answer to this anywhere online.

[image]

Comment: can you provide a clipping of what exactly you want to replicate

Comment: @ritikkumarsrivastava Have done so.

Comment: you are talking about the white dash or the start chat button?

Comment: As much as I know, it comes by default on iOS. else, you can wrap with stack and align it on bottom.

Comment: @AnasNadeem The white dash -- Android's gesture navigation bar. As said in my original message

Comment: It should work with bottomNavigationBar

Answer (score 0):

Okay, looks like this isn't quite possible yet, but is in the works, or possibly available on certainv ersions of flutter. I don't understand all of it myself but there's info here for anyone interested - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/69999